# Whatever and whichever usage

Tags: relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, inversion

1. Whatever Alice offers him, Fred eats.
2. Whatever you like, you may take.
3. Whichever wing succeeded first would wheel inwards and help the other.

Why the 3rd example does not have a comma after the starting subordinate clause (as in the first two)?

The only difference I could make out is that in the first two examples, the whatever clause is the complement (object) of the sentence and in the last one it is the subject.

Comment: It appears that you found these sentences somewhere. Please [cite the sources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: Original[?] discussion: https://www.englishforums.com/English/WhateverWhicheverUsageQuery/bqkgqv/post.htm

Comment: That is me in that forum. He helped me for sure. Want more clarification and details. The sources are from here. https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/whatever

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2) are written in inverted form. You might just as well write *Fred eats whatever Alice offers him.* The inversion is in order to emphasise *whatever* by putting it at the beginning of the sentence.

The third sentence is not in inverted form. *Whichever  wing* is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have replied as an answer as this comment section does not allow me to type in more than certain characters.